# Virtualizing test operating systems for writing scripts

Tags: virtualbox

I'm often writing bash scripts for auto-configuration of servers, and I'd like to be able to test them on live machines, rather than just hoping that they'll work when I need them to. I thought  of using VirtualBox, but the problem is that I don't want to have to go through and undo my changes every time I want to run the script. Is there a way to basically store a machine's state and revert back to it whenever I want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yep you want to use VirtualBox snapshots to revert the vm back to before you ran the script.

http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch01.html#snapshots

Comment: Also all virtualisation solution provide some way of snapshotting.  At the very least, if the vm uses a disk image, you can just copy the disk image file prior to making changes.